# location.hash and iframe conflict with IE version less than 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

Please anybody helps me.

I made a JS(target.js as below) which makes iframe like below.

I'm not sure with the cause, but onload function doesn't work on IE 9,8.

When I deleted the script tag, the onload function works and window scrolled to anchor.

```
<body onload="location.hash='#hashparam';">

HTML

<!-- Target part -->
<script params="parameters" src="target.js"></script>
<iframe src="target.html?parameters">
    <html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
          <script src="target-inner.js"></script>
          many iframes which are made by the script tags
       </body>
    </html>

HTML

</body>
```

Does anyone know the cause?
If you know about it, please teach me.

---

```
// target-inner.js
isIE = /MSIE/.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
isIE10 = /MSIE 10/.text(window.navigator.userAgent);
if (isIE10 || !isIE) {
    doc.clear();
    doc.open;
}
doc.write("<html><head></head><body>");
doc.write(text);
doc.write("</body></html>");
if (isIE10 || !isIE) {
    return doc.close();
} else {
    return;
}
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle.net simulating this error?

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I'll search jsfiddle.net and try to create a jsfiddle.net.

Comment: When I delete inner iframes, the onload function worked.
By any chance, double-iframe is the cause.

Comment: the onload will be invoked only when the iframe pages are loaded, so you can assume that the bug is with the iframes, analyse the code you use to generate the iframe... also check if the browser show any javascript error

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I'll research the cause with your advice.

Comment: I found the cause.
On IE9, iframe blocks body onload function.
And then, in my script there no document.close() with IE9.
onload function is blocked forever because of it.

But, in my script if I add document.close() after document.write with IE9, IE9 is crushed.
So I change the way to implement, I added the main function to body onload part. It works. Thank you fmodos for your kindness.

Comment: cool... this is important information. I suggest you to post an answer with this information in this question

Comment: I'm sorry I'm late to reply. Thank you. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause.

On IE9, iframe blocks body onload function.
And then, in my script there no document.close() with IE9.
onload function is blocked forever because of it.
But, in my script if I add document.close() after document.write with IE9, IE9 is crushed.
So I change the way to implement, I added the main function to body onload part.
It works.

Thank you fmodos for your kindness.